# how to send real time data from my db to a minimal HTML with django channels?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, websocket, django-channels

I`ve read many topic but still not clear. like https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/databases.html
I have a project in Django with two apps, one app save data into postgres and I want to send the stored data to a client asynchronously by the other app via django channels.

my model contains two fields "data" and "created_date" and I want send those data into websocket client.
I got no errors but data doesn`t show on html
any thought?

consumers.py

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from save.models import WebhookData


class MyConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    # async def receive(self, text_data):
    #     data = json.loads(text_data)
    #     # Get data from Postgres using Django ORM
    #     queryset = WebhookData.objects.all()
    #     # data = [{'id': obj.id, 'name': obj.name} for obj in queryset]
    #     data = [{'id': obj.id} for obj in queryset]
    #     print(data)
    #     # Send data to the client
    #     await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(data))


    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        # Get data from Postgres using Django ORM
        queryset = WebhookData.objects.all()
        result = []
        for obj in queryset:
            result.append({'data': obj.data})
        print(result)
        # Send data to the client
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(result))
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Async Data Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Async Data Example</h1>
<ul id="data-list"></ul>
<script>
    // Open a WebSocket connection to the server
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws/myapp/');

    // When the WebSocket connection is opened
    socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
        console.log('WebSocket connection opened.');
    });

    // When a message is received from the server
    socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log('Received data:', data);

        // Update the list of data items in the HTML page
        const dataList = document.getElementById('data-list');
        dataList.innerHTML = '';

        data.forEach(function (item) {
            const listItem = document.createElement('li');
            listItem.textContent = item.id;
            dataList.appendChild(listItem);
        });
    });

    // When the WebSocket connection is closed
    socket.addEventListener('close', function (event) {
        console.log('WebSocket connection closed.');
    });

    // When an error occurs with the WebSocket connection
    socket.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
        console.error('WebSocket error:', event);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you show the error in your code , then it will be more clear. One more thing your queryset variable will not get data as you are using it inside async function and you need to await it , use database_sync_to_async decorator and create a function for that . And show the error or give a better look to your problem .